# Is there any way to view a DataProc cluster's 'scheduled deletion' property in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm writing a cloud function that basically iterates over all our DataProc clusters and alerts us when they don't have a scheduled deletion policy. As I understand it this can be viewed in the CLI with `gcloud beta dataproc clusters list` but I am struggling to find a Python equivalent.

Has anyone done something similar in the past and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found the answer myself, it's in the config if you import `dataproc_v1beta2` instead of `dataproc_v1`